# trying to convert iso 8601 time to be used with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I'm trying to read a csv file that has a date that looks like this: 2018-02-20T22:41:33.793000Z and I can't figure out how to use that as the x axis in matplotlib.  I obviously have no idea what I"m doing with datetime because I can't seem to get it to be usefull numbers for matplotlib.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime
from datetime import datetime


data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'new.csv'))





fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

b = data.iloc[:, 8] #reading from column 8
a = pd.to_datetime(b, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ', errors='ignore')
print(a)

x = a #date  #.iloc[:, 0] grabs column without header
y = data.iloc[:, 2] #number  #reading from column 2
z = data.iloc[:, 6] #quantity #reading from column 6
#c = data.bluered   #blue or red


ax.scatter(x, y, z)  #ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=c)
plt.xlim(-1, 35)
plt.ylim(0, 300)
ax.set_zlim(-1,150)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much frustration I found the problem I was having was just simply to change plt.xlim(-1, 35) to plt.xlim('2018-02-20 22:41:26.419000','2018-02-20 22:48:55.768000')...which is the date/time range I was looking at.